# php sql server help needed

Tags: php, sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

Can any one suggest me a good framework for working with SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: Define "framework". Also, define "good".

Comment: Describe what do you need it for

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) and [Oracle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) extensions for PHP? This would be the obvious way of working with SQL Server and Oracle from PHP.

You could also try the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension for PHP.  It provides a consistent interface for working with different database engines.  It has support for both SQL Server and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to connect to, and modify your database with PHP, something I use and recommend is the ADOdb library ( http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ )

It allows you to abstract the database calls and use common functions for your application that are not database specific. I like this approach as I work on multiple projects that have different database requirements and it allows my code to be more portable, meaning no matter what database I am using, the code never has to change if I want to reuse it.

It also helps with code consistency across projects, and over time will help you maintain those apps more efficiently as they using a "standard" way of doing things.